# Why is string.charAt(x) much slower than string[x]

Tags: java, string

In Java (maybe the same for other langues as well) the `charAt(x)` method for accessing characters in a string is much slower than accessing the character elements in a `char[]`. This doesn't make much sense to me since String is using a `char[]` to represent the data.

Here is my test and results on this.

Testing `charAt()`

```
for(int i = 1000000; i >= 0; i--){
    char c = s.charAt(5);
}
```

`charAt()` elapsed time = 0.00261095

```
for(int i = 1000000; i >= 0; i--){
    char c = sArr[5];
}
```

`arr[]` elapsed time 0.001620297

From String.Java

```
public char charAt(int index) {
    if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
        throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
    }
    return value[index];
}
```

Comment: How did you measure the elapsed time?

Comment: [How do I write a correct micro-benchmark in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/504103)

Comment: is there still a big difference if you also include the range check into the loop (which String does)?

Comment: How many times did you find the elapsed time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error check inside of the `charAt()` method is actually accounted for the difference. The test that I created wasn't “fair”, the `char[x]` test doesn't have error handling so the times were faster

//error check from `charAt()`

```
if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
    throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
}
```

Updated `arr[x]` test with the following

```
    for(int i = 1000000; i >= 0; i--){
        if(dummy < 0 || dummy >= sArr.length) throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        char c = sArr[5];
    }
```

updated time: arr[] elapsed time 0.002208887

A lot closer to `charAt(i)` now.

Comment: Whether instructions are received on a rising or falling portion of a pulse can also offset the usage of finding elapsed time. At least it's that way in C.

Answer (score 2):

Offhand, I can think of at least a couple of reasons:

1. `charAt` is a method call
2. In Java 1.7.0_05 *(thanks for the precise version, [Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger))* and below, within `charAt`, `String` does work to determine which entry in the underlying `char[]` to give you, since strings can share `char[]` arrays:

   ```
   if ((index < 0) || (index >= count)) {
       throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
   }
   return value[index + offset];
   ```

   (`offset` is the offset in the shared `char[]`.)

   In Java 1.7.0_06 and above, it still does a range check:

   ```
   if ((index < 0) || (index >= value.length)) {
       throw new StringIndexOutOfBoundsException(index);
   }
   return value[index];
   ```

So we can see that `charAt` does what you're doing (accessing a `char[]` entry), but **also** has to have the overhead of a method call and the range check (and in Java 7 and earlier, the `index + offset` calculation). It can't help but be a bit slower.

Then there's the [possibility of measurement error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/504103/how-do-i-write-a-correct-micro-benchmark-in-java?lq=1), as naive micro-benchmarks in Java tend to be problematic.

Answer (score 2):

If you take a look at the [source code of String](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/lang/String.java), you will realise that once you call the method, two checks are being made on the provided index. Other than this, a method consumes some time by itself when called. These two combined are responsible for the time delay you noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Because charAt() is a method and it needs to be placed on the runtime stack and control needs to be altered each time it is called, which takes a little bit of time. To the best of my knowledge they both perform the same operation.

Comment: plus the index range check